# How do film makers record the President of the United States?

Tags: production

Some action films feature a scene, often at the beginning of the movie, where the acting President of the United States is seen talking about an issue related to the plot of the film. A good example of that is at the beginning of Dawn of the Planet of the Apes at around 2:00, according to Netflix's time-stamp. In this example, Barack Obama can be seen talking about getting "your family ready for evacuation".

How do filmmakers obtain those video sequences? I can imagine that in some cases, at least, they can use real footage of past speeches but I also cannot imagine that this would be a fitting solution all the time.

So what do they do? Does the White House schedule a day where filmmakers submit texts they want the acting president to say and possibly pay for it?

Comment: The movie Contact generated a bit of controversy doing this. http://www.nytimes.com/1997/07/11/movies/it-s-clinton-but-he-s-not-moonlighting.html

Comment: The future: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Yq67CjDqvw

Answer (score 93, accepted):

> Does the White House schedule a day where film makers submit texts they want the acting president to say and possibly pay for it?

### Absolutely not

Pretty much anything the President says in public is recorded on film.

Editing real footage of presidential statement into movies is an old practise.

It's just a matter of finding the right quote which, **out of context**, fits the plot of the movie in question.

You will usually find this referred to as ["archive footage"](http://rise-of-the-planet-of-the-apes.wikia.com/wiki/Barack_Obama)

For instance that clip is taken from this announcement on Hurricane Irene around the 1.20 mark:

[image]

Comment: *"It's just a matter of finding the right quote which, **out of context,** fits the plot... in question."*  Curiously enough, this is also a common practice for the opposition when an election is coming up.

Comment: One thing to note is that anything produced by the US government its in the public domain, so archival footage taken from a source like WH.gov can be used in a film without having to pay any fees or royalties.

Comment: "that clip" I see no clip, link? thanks :)

Comment: @RossRidge: "anything produced by the US government its in the public domain" I know I'm being a pedant here, but that's not true. The military, CIA, NSA are all part of the government and the information they produce is not public at all. You're referring to the government's **public** statements.

Comment: The clip in the movie...I added an image so one can see the comparison.

Comment: Being in public domain, and having a right to use someones likeness in your commercial product seem to me very different, legally.

Comment: @Flater Any work that the military, CIA and NSA produce is in the public domain as far as the US Copyright Act is concerned. Being in the public domain in this sense means that no one owns the copyright on the work. It doesn't mean it can't also be a classified secret or otherwise private information. On the other hand being in the public domain in the sense you're using doesn't mean that it can used for free. For the example the movie Dawn of the Planet of the Apes is out in the public domain in the sense that it's been made available to the public, however the copyright is owned by someone.

Comment: @RossRidge: Though you may be right about the copyright in _theory_, this is not the case in practice. Consider Edward Snowden. The US government has not just gone after Snowden for _leaking_ the documents, it has also gone after anyone who _publically hosted_ the leaked files. Even if you argue that Americans themselves need to adhere to what the US government classifies as a secret, that does not apply to foreign hosters. Yet the US government has gone after them too, claiming ownership over the documents (this international claim solely relies on **copyright**)

Comment: @RossRidge: "On the other hand being in the public domain in the sense you're using doesn't mean that it can used for free." That is not the sense that I was using. I was using it similar to why papparazi are able to publish pictures of celebrities out in public without their explicit consent. Similarly, a statement made by the White House out in public would be equally free to use without explicit permission. Note that the linked video does not take place in a White House press room or similarly private location.

Comment: @Flater Anything produced by the U.S. federal government is not covered by copyright *within U.S. jurisdiction*. Non-U.S. jurisdictions apply their copyright laws normally to works produced by the U.S. federal government, which the U.S. government may use to pursue legal action for unauthorized distribution. They're would be any distinction between public and private statements in that regard, I expect. (See https://www.usa.gov/government-works: "A government work is generally not subject to copyright *in the United States*... anyone may, ... *under U.S. copyright laws*... reproduce" etc)

Comment: Also, personality rights, copyright, and distribution controls (e.g., classification markings) are hugely different areas of law; there seems to be a lot of confusion over the three here.

Comment: @apsillers I appreciate the response and references. However, does the fact that copyright law exists internationally on these works not inherently imply that copyright **exists** on these works, but there is an additional law that specifically _exempts_ US jurisdictions from copyright limitations? Legally speaking, a specific subset of usages being exempt from copyright law is not the same as not having any copyright on these works.

Comment: @Flater Copyright on a work doesn't "naturally" exist except as far as a particular nation's laws "manufactures" it. U.S. law doesn't create copyright for federal government works; other nations, by default, do. [USC 17 sect. 105](https://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap1.html#105) merely says, "Copyright protection under this title is not available for any work of the United States Government..." so U.S. law does not afford any exclusive copyright rights to federal works. Another country's laws may do so, which would be relevant when bringing a claim in that country's jurisdiction.

Comment: @Paulie_D sorry for blowing up your notifications; this should probably get moved to chat.

Comment: Also, pay attention to when you can SEE the president versus when you can HEAR the president. Often they splice snippets from different speeches for dramatic effect, but cut away to panicked people on couches when it's from a different setting.

Comment: There was an episode of Mythbusters in which the hosts were talking to then-President Barack Obama, and it was quite apparent that he was saying things that he would not have said if he was not talking to the Mythbusters hosts.  Using archive footage may be easier than scheduling time with the President, but that doesn't mean the latter never happens.

Comment: @supercat This question is about fictional movies while MythBusters is a non-fictional science show. Of course they're not going to completely fake a meeting with the president.

Comment: @eesiraed: No, but there's no particular reason the President of the United States should be able to take the time to appear on Mythbusters and not to appear in a piece of dramatic fiction.

Answer (score 32):

In addition to [Paulie_D's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/78241/48480) which is the simplest and most prevalent method upto now:

CGI and computer technology has advanced to a point where it is possible to take some footage of a person, dub some new speech and have the footage resync the person's mouth movements to fit the new speech.

While not as advanced, there have also been times where clever editing has allowed new speech to be dubbed over footage of a president or other notable figure - usually by using only a longshot, or an oblique or rear angle to prevent the visual disconnect of bad lip-synchronisation.

Comment: Depending on the words, sometimes it's not even necessary to change the video portion at all. Bad Lip Reading videos demonstrate this very simply.

Comment: I think Mr Robot did this in season 2.

Comment: Now the question is how to find a footage in millions of them that nearly perfectly synchronises with the new dub

Comment: @Ooker You don't need to find footage that fits the new dub; you can edit any existing footage: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVBe6_o4cMI

Comment: This was done three times in Forrest Gump.

Comment: @TG01 And Bill Clinton's "appearance" in Contact (1997) too.

Comment: @ToddWilcox It's also how you can turn a Presidential debate [into a duet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jB2zoidUeLU).